# Checkout a git subdirectory into a particular folder

Tags: git

I would like to use the [Sodium](https://github.com/SodiumFRP/sodium) library in a project I am working on, but I need to have a bit of a practice and get up to speed with it. However I also want to work in my usual way of having all my dependencies under the folder `ext/`.

```
mkdir Test
cd Test
git init
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo c++/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git remote add -f sodium https://github.com/SodiumFRP/sodium.git
git pull sodium master
```

This gives me just the `c++/` folder in the root of Test which is not particularly helpful.  I would prefer it to be in the `ext/` folder and be named something other than `c++`. Renaming the folder causes it to be seen as untracked which is undesirable as I can achieve that just by copying the files from a zip.

If I create an `ext/` directory and do the `pull` command from within it the `c++` folder is still created in the root, not where the pull command was performed.

Is there a way of pulling a specific branch and copying it to subdirectory of a different name?

Comment: Sounds like a kind of issue which is easily fixed with symlinks.

Comment: But you don't want to create the git repository in the ext directory as a submodule, right?

Comment: I don't want the entire Sodium repo, no.  I have no need of the Haskell, Java, etc. versions of the library.

Comment: Yeah, but you can still create the (sparse) Sodium repository in ext, and not in Test

Comment: I usually add UnitTest++ as a submodule, but when I looked for information on getting a subdirectory of a repo all I found was `sparse-checkout`.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, adding it via symlinks makes git think it is untracked. If I wanted that then I might as well simply copy the files.

Comment: @martin, so are you going to leave it at that? I can't see any information in the git documentation that would allow me to add a sparse sub module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do that:

Suppose you have a main project repository called main:

```bash
# for the sake of completeness
git init main 
cd main
```

Now, add a folder for your dependencies and make it a sparse checkout:

```bash
# make and change to directory
mkdir ext
cd ext

# sparse checkout of c++ directory only
git init
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo c++/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout

# add remote repository and check it out
git remote add -f sodium https://github.com/SodiumFRP/sodium.git
git pull sodium master
```

You then have a sparse checkout which you add as a submodule:

```bash
cd .. # go back to main repository

# add and commit submodule
git submodule add ./ext
git commit -m "Added submodule"
```

I tested that with git 1.9.1.

If you like, you can add another directory as to have a layout like:

```bash
main
  + ext        # multiple external dependencies
  |  + sodium
  |     + .git
  |     + c++
  + src        # main project source files
```

Comment: Ahhh. I hadn't considered making a copy of the remote repository inside the main repo and adding that as a submodule.

Comment: I tried using `git submodule add ./ext ./ext/sodium` to try and add just the a renamed c++ directory but it added the entire sodium tree (scala, rust, java, etc.).  Any ideas?

Comment: @graham.reeds Your remark is unclear to me: I guess what you mean is: When cloning the repository, you get the mentioned behaviour. Yes, you need to perform the first steps of the sparse checkout for each dependency by hand when cloning the repository for the first time. After that you can use `git submodule update` to update only the sparse checkout. A script could help here.

Comment: @graham.reeds Additionally, you should only add `./ext/sodium` as submodule and not also `./ext`. I would let the main repository handle the dependencies.

Comment: Going into more detail: I did the steps up to the part where I add it as a submodule. I hoped by specifying the name of the folder it would rename it - I do this with `git submodule add https://github.com/unittest-cpp/unittest-cpp.git ext/unittest++` to rename the unittest-cpp folder to unittest++.  While it has the effect of renaming it gets all the other folders that I don't want.

Comment: Ah, ok: No, you need to perform the add submodule part for each sparse checkout in a folder name of your choice, then you add the submodule by local folder only (like in my answer). The way you have done that checks out the remote repository completely, and not as a sparse checkout.

Comment: So how do you do that?  The reason is purely cosmetic but it feels cleaner to have the cmake file that comes with sodium in `ext/sodium/` and not `ext/sodium/c++/`.